# Cloud endpoints update method crashes at mgr.close()

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using google app engine for java as the backend for an android application and an iOS application. The problem is that the update method is giving a null pointer exception and the stacktrace is pointing to the mgr.close() method.

I altered the original update method to create an image serving url with the blobkey that is passed up in the object.

the serving url is successfully created and added to the object.

When I check the datastore viewer, the entity isn't getting updated with the new information so evidently the mgr.persist() method was failing. I switched to the mgr.merge() method and got the same result.

so when the code moves into the try/catch statement to persist or merge the updated object, it fails and the entity manager goes null. Then the next line of the code calls mgr.close() and the null pointer exception is logged.

here is the method in question:

```
    @ApiMethod(name = "updateParty")
    public Party updateParty(Party party) {
    if (party.getFlyerServingUrl() == null && party.getFlyerStr() != null) {
         blob = new BlobKey(party.getFlyerStr());        
            options = Builder.withBlobKey(blob);
            final String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
            party.setFlyerServingUrl(servingUrl);
            if(party.getFlyerServingUrl() != null){
                log.info("Flyer serving url was generated and added to the party object.");
            }else{
                log.info("Flyer serving url was NOT generated.");
            }
            EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
            //update party with serving url             
            try {
                mgr.merge(party);           
            } finally {
                mgr.close();
            }
    }else{
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        //update party with serving url             
        try {
            mgr.merge(party);           
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

    }

    return party;
}
```

here is the log information:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:49)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityTranslator.convertToPb(EntityTranslator.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:203)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:180)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.<init>(Batcher.java:176)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$2.<init>(Batcher.java:311)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher.getBatches(Batcher.java:311)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchPut(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:536)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:490)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:444)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:86)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.put(WrappedDatastoreService.java:112)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.putEntitiesIntoDatastore(EntityUtils.java:766)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:314)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3778)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternalWithOrdering(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3888)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3811)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flush(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3751)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4141)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.transactionPreCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:428)
at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:398)
at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:287)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1090)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:193)
at com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint.updateParty(PartyEndpoint.java:406)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Were you a able to find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @user87049 I don't know if you are still looking for the answer to this but I posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush the Manager to execute the create/update statement.

```
try {
    mgr.merge(party);
    mgr.flush();           
} finally {
    mgr.close();
}
```

Comment: Nipper, you rock man!! Flushing the manager fixed it right away. What was going on with the entity manager and how did flushing fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem myself. The issue is with the way that cloud endpoints generates the update method. If you are using jpa with the datastore you will need to make these changes to every update method you have in your entity endpoint.

Here is some example code that shows how to fix the problem.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "updateMethod")
public Foo updateFoo(Foo foo) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = mgr.getTransaction(); //needed to get the object and change it.
    Foo updatedFoo = new Foo();
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        updatedFoo = mgr.find(Foo.class, foo.getKey().getId());
        updatedFoo.setFooProperty(foo.getFooProperty());//this is how you update the object's properties
        mgr.persist(updatedFoo);//persist the updated object
        transaction.commit();
        mgr.refresh(updatedFoo); //refresh the updated object in the datastore
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return updatedFoo;
}
```

Comment: what to do if your entity has about a gazillion properties?